# Github desktop application - Nothing added to commit but untrack files present

Tags: git, github

This question has been asked a lot, but I am specifically looking for a way to solve this with the Github Desktop application. I don't know how to use it, in fact this is my very first time publishing anything to Github, and my friend recommended I used the desktop application because it's easier.

When I upload try to commit my folder (which is about 45 mbs), I am greeted with this message:

[image]

When I try to upload using the Github website, I'm told the folder is too big.

What do I do? I don't understand anything about Git

Comment: Why is the folder so large?

Comment: Maybe you need to gitignore some of your project, such as `/node_modules` if it's in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you're new to using git

Before you make any new commits, you have to add files to the repository, you can add all the files in a folder to git.

Open your folder in the terminal, if you're on Windows 10 or above, you can do the same either by right clicking in the folder containing files and opening the terminal or by entering `cmd` in the address bar.

[image: right-click]

or

[image: cmd-terminal]

then add the files to your repository by using the `git add` command, to add all files use `git add .` (including the period) and press Enter. This will add all the files in the current directory to the Git repository.

Now that the files have been added to the repository, you can commit them. To do this, type `git commit -m "Initial commit"` (replacing "Initial commit" with a brief description of the changes you're committing) and press Enter.

Hopefully, this solves what you're facing, else feel free to ask any doubts you may have in the comments, I'll be happy to help.

You can use also use [these resources](https://github.com/TaufeeqRiyaz/Git-and-Github-BSc-RVU) if you're new to git